# How to add functionality for colorbox using a public function?

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

I want to make public function for colorbox, that will add some functionality to colorbox

```
$("#selector").colorbox({
        inline: true,
        popover: true,
})
```

now how can I access this popover inside my newPublicMethod?

```
(function($){

    $.fn.colorbox.settings.popover = false;

    $.fn.colorbox.myPublicMethod = function(abc){
        // how can i read the popover value here 
        if(popover){
           //somecode
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Rephrase your question? you want to add colorbox custom settings ?